# SelectedIndex = -1 with data bound Combo

Tags: asp.net, validation, combobox

Is there any equivalent to this when a combo is data bound? I've been through this hundreds of times before, but I'm having a brain freeze moment.

Comment: The SelectedIndex = -1 implies that there is not an option within the dropdown selected...  Can you add more of the code?

Comment: I _want_ to have no option selected!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In asp.net the closest you could get is to add in a false item such as "---Select Something---" and have it as index 0, then you would set and perform checks on index 0 instead of -1.

Example:

```
dropdownlist1.datasource = DT
dropdownlist1.datatextfield = "EmployeeName"
dropdownlist1.datavaluefield = "EmployeeID"
dropdownlist1.databind

dropdownlist1.items.insert(0, "---"Select An Employee---")

dropdownlist1.selectedindex = 0
```

Then during your validation you could make sure to check to make sure `selectedindex <> 0`

Answer (score 1):

A trick I've done in the past, is that if your DataValue field is going to be a numeric field (such as an Id), you can assign a range validator object to it and check that the value itself is greater than 0. I then create my "select" item to have a value of -99 and I can then perform validation on the client side.